# Maximum Attachment Size in database mail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-mail

Good Afternoon,

I am trying to send an attachment via database mail.

```
declare     @mail_recipients  VARCHAR(4000)  = 'abc@123.com'
          , @mail_subject     VARCHAR(500)   = 'subject'
          , @mail_body        VARCHAR(4000)  = ''
          , @mail_attachment  VARCHAR(500)   = ''
          , @sql_query        VARCHAR(4000)  = ''

..... Code to populate the query

EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail   @profile_name                 = {our profile name}
                          , @recipients                   = @mail_recipients
                          , @subject                      = @mail_subject
                          , @body                         = @mail_body
                          , @body_format                  = 'HTML'
                          , @query_result_header          = 1 
                          , @query                        = @sql_query
                          , @attach_query_result_as_file  = 1
                          , @query_attachment_filename    = @mail_attachment
                          , @query_result_separator       = ','
```

I am getting the following error.

> Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   File attachment or query results size exceeds allowable value of 10000000 bytes.

When I run this in SSMS, and SAVE-AS csv file, the file is only 9077 KB.  What would database mail be doing to make it think the file is so much bigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file, when sent as an attachment, is converted into [7-bit ASCII](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323489), which makes the file a lot bigger than it would normally appear to be.

As @M.Ali pointed out in his answer, you can adjust the maximum message size to accommodate your large query.

However, what are you sending via email that needs to be so big?  Are you *sure* that amount of info, in what likely amounts to a report, is actually being used by the recipient?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately they are using every column in the report.  Limiting the result set was my first question.    Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You will have to change the allowed Attachment file size by going to the following location:

Go to `SQL Server Management Studio` -->  `Management` -->  `Database Mail`

This will fire up the `Configuration Wizard`.

Click `Next` --> Select `View or change system parameters` --> click `Next`.

Now change the Maximum File Size (Bytes) property and click Next, then click Finish to save your changes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I knew changing the size would help,.  But, wondering why the difference in sizes. thank you!

Comment: @MaxVernon you are right, actually I didn't know myself until I read your answer :)